# Json.asString returns None even though Json.toString returns the correct value

Tags: json, scala, circe

Given the following case class `LogMessage`:

```scala
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.{deriveDecoder, deriveEncoder}
import enumeratum.{CirceEnum, Enum, EnumEntry}
import io.circe.syntax._

sealed trait LogLevel extends EnumEntry

object LogLevel extends Enum[LogLevel] with CirceEnum[LogLevel] {
  val values = findValues

  case object Warning extends LogLevel
  case object Error   extends LogLevel
  case object Info    extends LogLevel
  case object Success extends LogLevel
}

object LogMessage {
  implicit val logMessageDecoder: Decoder[LogMessage] = deriveDecoder[LogMessage]
  implicit val logMessageEncoder: Encoder[LogMessage] = deriveEncoder[LogMessage]
}

case class LogMessage(level: LogLevel, text: String, args: List[String], date: Long)
```

```scala
case class MyClass[A](obj: A)(implicit encoder: Encoder[A]) {
    def message1: String = obj.asJson.toString
    def message2: Option[String] = obj.asJson.asString
}
```

Why does this work:

```scala
val x = MyClass(LogMessage(LogLevel.Info, "test notification", Nil, 1550218866571))

x.message1 // {\n  "level" : "Info",\n  "text" : "test notification",\n  "args" : [\n  ],\n  "date" : 1550218866571\n}
```

But this does not:

```scala
x.message2 // None
```

Here is a link to Scastie with this problem: [link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TxXQ39wdQbKqQcRX9ZHZfQ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In circe `Json` has six `asX` methods that correspond to the six data types in JSON. For example, if a `Json` instance `x` represents a JSON boolean, `x.asBoolean` will return a `Some` containing the value as a `Boolean`, but if `x` is a JSON string, array, object, number, or null, `x.asBoolean` will be empty.

You're seeing `.asString` return `None` in this case because you're calling it on a `Json` value that represents a JSON object, not a JSON string.

The `toString` method on `Json` is completely different: it's the universal Scala / Java `toString`, which in the case of `Json` is implemented as `.spaces2`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but in general I'd recommend avoiding `toString`—if you want to serialize an `io.circe.Json` value, it's better to use a printer or the printing methods that make the formatting options more explicit (e.g. `noSpaces`, `spaces2`, etc.).

(For what it's worth, I'm not entirely happy with the naming of `asString`, `asNull`, etc. methods on `Json`. In general in circe "as" is used in method names for encoding or decoding, which isn't exactly what's happening in these cases, but it's close enough that I've never bothered to come up with a better alternative.)